# Plot a filled black circle on a certain background in Matlab

Tags: matlab, background, grayscale

I have a 344*344 grey-level image with noise only. Now I want to plot a filled black circle in the middle of that gray image as background.
How can I achieve that? And I hope I can also adjust the size (scale) of the filled black circle in the middle of the image.
Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Plotting Filled Circle On Greyscale Image

By calculating the distance from the midpoint of the image for each of the pixels a circle can be generated. By setting each of the pixels to an intensity of 0 that does not satisfy the radius threshold the impression of a circle can be achieved.

• Magnitude From Centre = (X - X_Midpoint)^2 + (Y - Y_Midpoint)^2

[image: Image with Adjustable Circle Fill]

[image: Image with Adjustable Ellipse]

```
%Adjust for ellipse%
Scaling_Factor_1 = 3;
Scaling_Factor_2 = 1;


%Importing image%
Image = imread('Tiger_Drawing.jpg');
Image = rgb2gray(Image);

%The radius of the filled circle%
Radius = 100;

%Grabbing the dimensions of the image%
[Image_Height,Image_Width] = size(Image);

%Evaluating the midpoint of the image%
Image_Midpoint = [round(Image_Height/2), round(Image_Width/2)];

%Scanning through the pixels of the image%
for Row_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Height
   for Column_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Width 
      
      
      
%The pixel coordinate%
Pixel_Coordinate = [Row_Scanner Column_Scanner];
Magnitude_From_Centre = sqrt((abs(Pixel_Coordinate(1,1) - Image_Midpoint(1,1))^2)/Scaling_Factor_1 + abs(Pixel_Coordinate(1,2) - Image_Midpoint(1,2))^2/Scaling_Factor_2);



%If the magnitude from the centre is smaller than the set radius set
%intensity to 0%
if(Magnitude_From_Centre <= Radius) 
    Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner) = 0; 
end 

   end 
end


imshow(Image);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thank you so much! Now the challenge is... how about an ellipse?

Comment: No problem, for simplicity I would add scaling factors. I updated the answer with that. How much precision and flexibility did you need? This equation explains the scaling factors [a] and [b] https://www.google.com/search?q=ellipse+equation&sa=X&bih=745&biw=1088&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=7LR2MRVKMne8uM%252CuE7IdaUNI5j3rM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQLCxT17GSzRpfz2Pu1Py-xRDs9qw&ved=2ahUKEwj0srr_yJTrAhW4lHIEHYIVBFEQ_h0wAHoECAQQBA#imgrc=7LR2MRVKMne8uM

Comment: Essentially the scaling factors can be thought of as weights that indicate how significant the x-component and y-components are in calculating the magnitude/distance from the centre of the image.